# ./<filename> No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, executable, binary

I'm trying to run a binary. But when I'm trying to run the file I'm facing the following error.

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ./house_of_force 
bash: ./house_of_force: No such file or directory
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ldd ./house_of_force 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7c6da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3f879bd000)
    ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f87bf9000)
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ file ./house_of_force 
./house_of_force: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=278a2aec8b352ea120c49321ed3254eb15ca8ef5, with debug_info, not stripped
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ readelf -l house_of_force 

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400730
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x0000000000000027 0x0000000000000027  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000d88 0x0000000000000d88  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001d70 0x0000000000601d70 0x0000000000601d70
                 0x00000000000002c0 0x00000000000002c8  RW     0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000001d80 0x0000000000601d80 0x0000000000601d80
                 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000260 0x0000000000400260 0x0000000000400260
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000c04 0x0000000000400c04 0x0000000000400c04
                 0x000000000000004c 0x000000000000004c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000001d70 0x0000000000601d70 0x0000000000601d70
                 0x0000000000000290 0x0000000000000290  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

My System Details:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ uname -a
Linux pegasus 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I've already done `chmod a+x house_of_force`
What I'm suspecting some shared object or the interpreter is broken.
I'm unable to link them properly.

Help me running the file properly using `./house_of_force`

Comment: Usually that means the binary interpreter (`../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2`, here) doesn't exist. Or similarly in the case of a script, it'd mean the hashbang interpreter doesn't exist.

Comment: I actually have the glibc. and all the stated directories and files. But exactly on which directory should I have it.

Comment: If the interpreter is `../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2` (a relative path, I didn't expect that to even work) and your current working directory is `~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force`, you need `~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/ld.so.2` to exist before you can hope for it to work.

Comment: and what's with the
`/.glibc/`
directory 
Like how can a directory name start with a dot (.) 
Does it mean a hidden directory?
I've the glibc directory but why is a dot used before the directory name

Comment: After I've added the linker. Now it's broken

```pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Courses/heaplab-main/house_of_force$ ldd house_of_force 
./house_of_force: error while loading shared libraries: ../.glibc/glibc_2.28_no-tcache/libc.so.6: file too short```

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you just run following command then everything will be fine

```
git clone https://github.com/one2blame/heaplab.git
```

Then enter the directory and run the `house_of_force`

Comment: how does this help?

Comment: Copying or move from external sources to virtual machine will corrupt the files. Please directly  download the source file .

Comment: wouldn't github.com also be an external source? Why doesn't copying files from there corrupt them all the same?